# Is hadees of jama tirmizi .257 sahih or hassan or daif

Tags: authenticity, uloom-al-hadith

Is the hadees in jama tirmizi whose hadees number is 257 is sahih or hassan or daif

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As is written this question is not well posed please add all necessary information in your post without the full hadith quote we can only guess which hadith you are referring to since none of the hadith compilation authors has added any number as a reference these numbers are only valid for specific printed editions! (see [ask]).

Answer (score 1):

In this hadith: Abu 'Isa (probably referring to Imam At-Tirmidhi) said, "The hadith of Ibn Mas'ud is a Hasan hadith":

> حَدَّثَنَا هَنَّادٌ، حَدَّثَنَا وَكِيعٌ، عَنْ سُفْيَانَ، عَنْ عَاصِمِ بْنِ كُلَيْبٍ، عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ الأَسْوَدِ، عَنْ عَلْقَمَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ مَسْعُودٍ أَلاَ أُصَلِّي بِكُمْ صَلاَةَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَصَلَّى فَلَمْ يَرْفَعْ يَدَيْهِ إِلاَّ فِي أَوَّلِ مَرَّةٍ ‏.‏ قَالَ وَفِي الْبَابِ عَنِ الْبَرَاءِ بْنِ عَازِبٍ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو عِيسَى حَدِيثُ ابْنِ مَسْعُودٍ حَدِيثٌ حَسَنٌ ‏.‏ وَبِهِ يَقُولُ غَيْرُ وَاحِدٍ مِنْ أَهْلِ الْعِلْمِ مِنْ أَصْحَابِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَالتَّابِعِينَ ‏.‏ وَهُوَ قَوْلُ سُفْيَانَ الثَّوْرِيِّ وَأَهْلِ الْكُوفَةِ ‏.‏

[Source for the above hadith](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:257)

Complete translation, which I got from (modifications were made) [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com):

> > "We were informed by Hannad, who was informed by Wakee', from Sufyan, from 'Asim ibn Kulayb, from 'Abd al-Rahman ibn al-Aswad, from 'Alqamah, who said: 'Abdullah ibn Mas'ud said, 'Shall I not perform the prayer of the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) for you?' He then prayed and did not raise his hands except in the initial takbir (saying "Allahu Akbar").'"
>
> > Abu 'Isa said: "The hadith of Ibn Mas'ud is considered a good (hasan) hadith, and several knowledgeable individuals among the companions of the Prophet and the successors (tabi'in) have narrated it. It is the view of Sufyan al-Thawri and the people of Kufa."

So according to Abu 'Isa this hadith is hasan, but according to the Darussalam Grade the hadith is Da'if as per this hadith on [sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:257)

So, Abu 'Isa held the view of the hadith being Hasan while the Darussalam grade given is Da'if. Scholars may or may not disagree on the authenticity of some hadith in their grading.

It is possible that I am wrong, because I am human and Allah knows best.